# Create list-of-controls in Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have decided that I would like to have a list with "complex context", i.e. of custom-controls. (The goal is something looking like a buddy list, with photos, status-icons, text, and "start-chat-button".)

But I like it to behave as a list: scrollbars, possibility to  select multiple items, etc.

When I have been looking at ListView and ListBox I only see that I can add text and an icon, but not arbitrary controls. I'm I missing how this is done?

Or should I use something else than ListView/ListBox?

Comment: why not try WPF rather than Winforms ?

Comment: @Dean Chalk: I am adding a feature to an existing application. Which is Windows.Forms.

Comment: Not to mention "trying" WPF would incur a steep learning curve if you haven't got any experience in it yet.

Comment: Learning at least basics of WPF can only benefit a C# developer in the future as MS is putting a lot of focus on it. Also, what OP is trying to do would be just a simple usage of XAML and data binding, which is covered in first chapters of all WPF tutorials.

Comment: @CommanderZ that is assuming what the OP wants to achieve is all that is written in the post.

Comment: More complex requirements would even more justify usage of WPF (at cost of some time required to learn required techniques in WPF, but again - for future benefit.)

Comment: The argument for future benefit is the ideal situation, but often the actual situation is better the devil you know.  WPF may not be used in the company, meaning if you choose to use it (which may not be your choice) you are staking responsibility for maintenance.  You might be able to achieve the basics, but not more advanced concepts.  These would incur more learning, greater risk of design issues, more bugs etc.  I totally agree WPF solves UI problems nicely, but the OP is in a WinForms application and it is tagged as WinForms, so presumably needs a WinForms solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a control buried in the Visual Basic Power Packs called [the Data Repeater](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx).

This allows you to associate your own controls with a data container that becomes an item in the repeater.

I've used it once before, and I believe it's not *entirely* intuitive, but once you've got your head around it, it can be fairly useful. It also saves rolling your own control.

It is currently the closest thing to the idea of an arbitrary repeating control in Windows Forms that I have found so far.

Answer (score 14):

Use a `FlowLayoutPanel`. If you want controls arranged vertically, with scrolling, do:

```
myFlowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
myFlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
myFlowLayoutPanel.WrapContents = false; // Vertical rather than horizontal scrolling
foreach(Control myControl in myControls){
    myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(myControl);
}
```

Make sure the panel is large enough to contain controls and scrollbar. I'm not sure about your selection requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This would be rather trivial to create in [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) (while it is going to be a lot of work in Windows Forms) - WPF is designed to create such rich-UI controls. If the rest of your app is in Windows Forms, you can host [WPF control in Windows Forms](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/hosting-wpf-controls-winforms).

Comment: It is also trivial in WinForms, there is a control available to do so in the Visual Basic Power Packs called the Data Repeater.  I agree that starting from nothing in WinForms is, however, not trivial.

Comment: Not everything is an XY problem. Sometimes there's a reason OP needs to use one system over another.